# How could you make TabBox to fill all available space?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

Does anybody know how I can make TabBox to fill all available space?
I tried this:

```
<tabbox id="MyTabBox" flex="1">
  <tabs>  
    <tab label="Income" />
    <tab label="Taxes" />
  </tabs>   
  <tabpanels flex="1">
    <tabpanel>
      <button label="Calculate" flex="0"/>
    </tabpanel>  
    <tabpanel> 
    </tabpanel>  
  </tabpanels>
</tabbox>
```

The TabBox looks fine, but this makes the Button to fill all the height of the first TabPanel, despite its flex attribute.
If I limit the height of the Button, that also makes the TabBox kind of short, not the way I need.

### Thank you.

Update: The window code now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://MyExtension/skin/MyExtension.css" ?>

<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://MyExtension/locale/translations.dtd">

<window id="MyExtension-MainWindow"
  title="My Extension"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html:link rel="icon" href="chrome://MyExtension/skin/MyExtensionFavIcon.png"/>

<tabbox id="MyTabBox" flex="1">
  <tabs>  
    <tab label="Income" />
    <tab label="Taxes" />
  </tabs>   
  <tabpanels flex="1">
    <tabpanel align="start">
      <button label="Calculate" flex="0"/>
    </tabpanel>  
    <tabpanel> 
    </tabpanel>  
  </tabpanels>
</tabbox>

</window>
```

FavIcon is Ok, Button is Ok, TabBox is shrunk, which sucks :-(

Comment: Could you add your source again, and this time use the 101/010 button to make it into code; it's lost all the angle brackets.

Comment: Hi, Pete KirKham. I did not know there was such a button. I posted a message, it was not accepted, than I read that no HTML tags are accepted, so I stripped all the brackets and posted it again. But it looks like some good man returned the brackets back. I am new to XUL and it does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: After your update: I don't really see what the problem is. By default the tabbox is only as big as it needs to be to contain the stuff that's in it. If you made the window resize-able then you can resize it. Or you could just add an explicit width/height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `align="center"` to the <s>button</s> tabpanel (Adding `align` to an element affects that element's children, not the element itself). See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/align) -- IIRC `stretch` is the default.

Comment: Hi, MatrixFrog. Thank you so much! This seems to solve it. Adding the align attribute to the button seems to only affect the position of the button's label, but when I added the align="start" attribute to the tabpanel element - everythig became just as I wanted, that is the tabbox fills all the window and the button still has its normal size.

Comment: Darn! Now I had added a favicon for my window and out of the blue the tabbox shrunk yet once again.

Comment: Still looking for help with it.

Comment: You might want to update your original question with some information about where exactly this icon is that you added.

Comment: Hi, MatrixFrog. Thanks for your help. I am guessing the XUL is like a puzzle. You can not just write code, you must puzzle it out.

Comment: I think *all* code is like that to some extent. It gets easier if you get better at reading the MDC wiki, which I admit is a little tricky at first. There's also some extensions you should keep handy: XUL Gear, DOM Inspector, Inspect Context are the main ones.

Comment: Thanks, MatrixFrog, again for the tip. I will certainly try them out. I miss Turbo Basic so! VB.NET is also pretty straightforward when it comes to coding UI. Most of the cases you set an attribute and get what you want. Why cannot they make all languages like that?! Still, returning to my question: are there no answers because it is impossible to set?

Comment: I found the problem and want to post the solution, but the "Answer your Question" button does not work. Why is that?

Comment: The problem in my case was in this line: <html:link rel="icon" href="chrome://MyExtension/skin/MyExtensionFavIcon.png"/>. Everything became Ok after I added and set "display" property to "none". The working code looks like this: <html:link rel="icon" href="chrome://MyExtension/skin/MyExtensionFavIcon.png" style="display:none"/>. Seems like Mozilla has a problem when inline elements are placed in improper context.